# Array asociativo con $Session php

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase, donde nos mandan hacer una aplicacion de para comprar billetes de tren. Estoy teniendo dudas a la hora de hacer el apartado asientos. Donde nos manda hacer que el cliente elija un vagon y que de ese vagón elija un asiento disponible que haya (debemos comprobar los asientos disponibles). En este ejercicio no se usan bases de datos, solo se usan variables Session para hacer el ejercicio. Estoy un poco perdido a la hora de hacerlo, a ver si me podéis echar una mano. No se si lo tengo bien, mal o que..

Esto es lo que tengo por ahora.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['destino'];
$_SESSION['fecha'];
$_SESSION['billete'];
$_SESSION['tarjeta'];
$vagon= $_POST['vagon'];
$_POST['vagon'] = array("Vagon1","Vagon2","Vagon3","Vagon4","Vagon5");
$asiento ['asiento']= $_POST['asiento'];
$_POST['asiento'] = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20");
$tren = [$vagon=>$asiento];
$_SESSION['tren'] = $tren;
if(isset($_POST['vagon']))$_SESSION['vagon'] = $_POST['vagon'];
if(isset($_POST['asiento']))$_SESSION['asiento'] = $_POST['asiento'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <h3>Elige un vagón
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio" name="vagon" value="Vagon1">
                            <label>Vagón 1</label>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <input type="radio"  name="vagon" value="Vagon2">
                            <label>Vagón 2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio"  name="vagon" value="Vagon3">
                            <label>Vagón 3</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio"  name="vagon" value="Vagon4">
                            <label>Vagón 4</label>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="radio"  name="vagon" value="Vagon5">
                            <label>Vagón 5</label>
                        </div>
            </h3>
                <input type="submit" name ="elegir"value="Elegir">
                <input type="submit" value="automatico" value="Automatico">

                <?php 
                $error ="";
                if(isset($_POST['elegir'])){
                    if(empty($vagon)){
                        echo $error = "No has elegido un vagón";

                    }else{
                        ?>
                <h2>Sistema de Compra de billetes "Renfe"</h2>
                <h3>Elige asiento</h3>
                <h4>Destino: <?php echo $_SESSION['destino']?></h4>
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="1">1
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="2">2
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="3">3
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="4">4
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="5">5
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="6">6
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="7">7
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="8">8
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="9">9
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="10">10
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="11">11
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="12">12
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="13">13
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="14">14
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="15">15
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="16">16
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="17">17
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="18">18
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="19">19
                <input type="checkbox" name="asiento" value="20">20
                        <?php
                    }

                }
                ?>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Debes dar más detalles para poder ayudarte. Por ejemplo, ¿los vagones son todos iguales, es decir, tienen la misma cantidad de asientos? Si es así, tienes que meter en cada vagón un array de asientos. La estructura debería quedar así más o menos: `array ( 'Vagon1'=>array('1,2,3,4...'), 'Vagon2'=>array('1,2,3,4...') )`

Comment: Si cada vagon tiene 20 asientos

Comment: Podrías manejar un array parecido a este: `$mTrain=array ( 
                'Vagon1'=>array(1=>true,2=>false,3=>false), 
                'Vagon2'=>array(1=>false,2=>false,3=>true), 
);` dentro de cada vagón habría un array con pares `unNumero=>unBooleano` que indicarían el nº de asiento y si ese asiento está ocupado o no. Por ejemplo ahí ya sabes que el asiento `1` de `Vagon1` y el asiento `3` de `Vagon2` están ocupados... Partiendo de ahí, puedes modificar el array o representar su estado en el HTML.